# How to find out if I've been hacked

Tags: apache-2.4, hacking

I am running Apache2 webserver and someone has attempted to hack me. using this [script](http://pastebin.com/vq2NggDT).

How can can find if the attack worked and what its done if it has worked. I'm running Kali Linux 2.0.

Further information:

So far,

1. I have checked my apache2 logs and have found this:
   ['part of my apache2 access.log.1'](http://pastebin.com/dUyV9ZEr)
2. I have done whois lookups and found the IP to be a french ISP and
       the IRC server of the bot in the script is based in china (probably
       due to relaxed laws).
3. I have set my firewall to only allow in on 80 for now but am
   worried what is going out. (If I set my firewall to only allow out on port 80 but then I can't connect to the web for some reason.)
4. I have checked my syslog (took hours to do)
5. I have monitored my traffic with wireshark - which shows no
   connections that shouldn't be there.
6. I have checked system monitor for a while but wouldn't know what
   processes shouldn't be there anyway.
7. Apache2 service is currently 'not active' :( (I felt it best to turn apache off while I learn about this)

The whole point in my setting up the server was to learn about hosting websites and servers from Linux machines using apache2. This is exactly what I wanted in a way so I can learn from this hack/mistake.   So now I'm lost and don't know what to do next.

What was cox.pl even trying to do?

How do I know if what it wanted to do worked?

Comment: Hire a security analyst to review your systems.  I know this isn't what you're looking for, but your ask is not a simple task.

Comment: Kali is made to test your security, maybe you can do a more complet question ? your apache2 is on which system, what test you did, etc ...?

Comment: @Colyn1337 I don't have a financial income at all I'm afraid, that is out of the question completely. Froggiz apache2 is on the kali system - felt it would be secure to run apache2 on and that i could test the server for vulnerabilities, The script has been wriiten by someone in perl ( I dont really understand perl) the lnik is not there for the script check the link.

Comment: Nuke from orbit and reinstall from known good backups.